# Django M2M through table delete and save methods

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a many to many relation between two tables and relation is saved in a through table:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=BookLike)

class User(models.Model):
    ...

class  BookLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

When a user likes or dislikes a book I want to carry out some actions like increasing/decreasing the like count of book for example. I tried overwriting save and delete functions of BookLike but they are not called when I call book_instance.likes.remove(user) and book_instance.likes.add(user). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong approach. If the `Book` model is connected to `User`, don't call `users` `likes`. Trust me that's going to bite you in the ass down the road.

So, first off:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField("User", through="BookUser", through_fields=('book', 'user'), related_name="books")

class User(models.Model):
    ...

class BookUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bookusers")
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bookusers")
```

Then, you don't need to overwrite the default model methods. All you need to do is to register books in users or viceversa exactly how you described.

```
user_instance.books.add(book_instance)
```

Then if you want to retrieve or count how many likes a book has you can run a simple query:

```
book_instance.users.count()
book_instance.users.all()
```

or

```
BookUser.objects.filter(book=book_instance).count()
```

or the exact opposite if you want to fetch info about a specific user

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to save the like count in the table instead of counting the records each time?

Comment: Performance wise or for you? If it's for performance, I would recommend you to hold back from making optimizations that you don't need yet. Once the time comes you can add a count field and keep it up to date with a signal.
For now if you don't want to spell out the query each time you can write a convenience method on the model, but the benefit would not be that big. You would trade `book_instance.users.count()` for `book_instance.users_count()` or something of the like.

Comment: When it comes to performance, caching is a better approach than creating redundant model fields anyway. So really think about it twice before going down that path

Comment: please if you found the answer helpful accept it or upvote it (or both) i'm trying to collect extra points to place a bounty on a question. Thank you